# WSL alternative for Linux on Windows 11 to work with VScode

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

The WSL is extremely underperforming and unreliable, but it is integrated to VScode.
Is there any other way to work locally on linux (Ubuntu) environment within VScode?

Comment: The only solution if WSL has been determined not to be a solution is to run a VM. However, there is little difference in performance between a VM and WSL, except the VM would be an isolated environment compared instead of an Integrated environment.  VSCode does not require WSL nor Linux to run and runs natively on Windows.